# navigationController and leaking

Tags: objective-c, ios

I used the instruments tool and it tells me I have no memory leaks. But I am struggling with the logic behind it. Why wouldn't this be leaky? It appears that some magic is happening behind the scenes and my AppDelegate is using my allocated navController to set the property of the self.navigationController. Without my initialization here, my property is nil.
Shouldn't I be forced to make these instance variables of the delegate and then release them in the dealloc? Why isn't this a leak? Or am I using the instruments tool wrong?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

      // two alloc calls which would imply I need a release 
  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
  UIViewController *calcController = [[CalculatorViewController alloc] init];

  [navController pushViewController:calcController animated:YES];

  [window addSubview:navController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

      // can not release here, if i do, no views show up
      // [navController release];
      // [calcController release];

      return YES;
}
...
// NOTE: No dealloc for navController or calcController
- (void)dealloc {
   [window release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `navController` and `calcController` exist for the life of the program. When the program terminates, everything is purged, so it doesn't matter. You do have a leak, but an irrelevant one.

Comment: Makes sense. What is going on with navController, is it magically being attached to the self.navigationController property? Would the code be sexier if I made them into instance variables? Or like you say, it just doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, because of this line: `[window addSubview:navController.view];` The controller is retained because its view is retained (by the window).

Comment: In this case, both controller then.. the navController and the view which is the calcController. You guys are very fast to respond. I love this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your app delegate exists for the duration of the application run, you would only see a memory leak right before the application quits.  So while there is technically a "leak" it only occurs right before the application is purged from memory.

Comment: tx simon. much appreciated. any thoughts on this... Would the code be sexier if I made them into instance variables? Or like you say, it just doesn't matter.